# Process stopped in unexpected step. Make sure that you defined all necessary connections

Tags: workflow, kentico

I'm having a problem with a Condition in a workflow:
[image]

The condition is:
[image]

Sending pages to Approval that match the condition are working as expected and moving to the Approve step:
[image]

However those that do not match the condition are getting stuck in the condition step and the email is not sent as expected:

[image]

I'm getting the following error on Event Log:
[image]

The connection is there and it's automatic, as you can see on the first image. Hence the question, anyone knows why this could be happening?

The "Send email to Jira" step is setup as follows (email redacted):
[image]

But I don't think it's even reaching it, as there's no other log entries for an email error, and the default emails from the workflow are indeed working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user wants to move page from Condition workflow step, he must have a Manage workflow permissions.

However since your role (CMS Approvers) most probably do not have this permissions - workflow process stuck with the error message.

Although the error message is not very descriptive (we can definitely improve this part) this is the reason of your issue.

To solve it, please navigate to the Security section of the Condition workflow step and set Roles which can approve, reject and make changes
section to All except listed as you can see here: http://prntscr.com/pdtrgs

Also please double check that CMS Approvers role has Manage workflow permission.

Then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate this issue in both Kentico 11.0.47 and Kentico 12.0.33. The strange thing about this is that an email does send if you reverse the steps. In other words, if the user is a global admin, then send an email. That works.

I'll need to ask the developers about this, and see if there is something we're both missing. Otherwise this looks like buggy behavior.

-Keith Hammond; Kentico Support